# Difference between properties file, JSON, and YAML?

Tags: selenium

I'm a beginner in testing. I am working in selenium with page object design pattern. I want to keep the test data separately but I'm still confused. I want to know the difference between the usage of the properties file, YAML, and JSON.

Is there any reason why I should use one of these file types for my test data? Does Selenium support one type of file for data better than the other types?

Comment: I've edited your question to be less opinion-based. Asking people what they prefer is not a good format for questions here - we're looking for questions that can have a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

[YAML](http://yaml.org/) is designed to be used by all programming languages:

> YAML is a human friendly data serialization standard for all
>   programming languages.

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) originated in the JavaScript world and is mostly used as data format between back-ends and JavaScript web-front-ends.

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange
>   format.

In the end it doesn't really matter which format you use. I would pick the one the team has the most experience with.

Comment: What is your opinion about properties file to keep the test data ?

Comment: I rather keep test-data in my code, but it greatly depends on how much data it is. Some data would be better in a database, some better in a config file, for most test-data I would create a test-data class which contains the necessary data.

Comment: An example would be an user object which contains multiple users with their settings/rights. In code I would use something like adminuser = new user(admin), login(adminUser), in the login function it would use user.password to get the data. Instead of login(getConfigFileUserData('admin').username, getConfigFileUserData('admin').password). My preference is that code should read like a story, readability is my highest priority, where the data is stored I could care less about.

Answer (score 0):

Properties file is a great option for scale-able test automation framework.
You can keep data in *key=value* pairs.
Anyone with limited technical expertise can easily add/remove properties without messing the format.
Reading properties file in Java is considerably easy with Properties class or File reading libraries.

Comment: In JSON or YAML you can have key/value pairs too.